# VBA file folder names in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I run Excel 2010 at work and have a VBA script that contains the following lines:

```
Set fd = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
'path name, modify as necessary
pthnm = "F:PolyTec\ToBeDone\"
Set fs = fd.GetFolder(pthnm)
```

This allows us to import data files from an external source (usually a flash drive).  I tried running this on Windows 8, Office 2013 at home [to work on a different part of the script] and got a "path not found" error.  Of course, the assigned drive letter was different.  When I fixed it, I kept getting the same error.  Is there something wrong with this code for version 2013?  I have never had a problem with it in 2010.

Comment: Try `pthnm = "F:\PolyTec\ToBeDone\"`

Comment: OK.  That makes sense.  Slipped through all these years.  Have to wait to get back on 2013 to check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing:

```
pthnm = "F:PolyTec\ToBeDone\"
```

with:

```
pthnm = "F:\PolyTec\ToBeDone\"
```